# How to get specific value without parsing xml in java

Tags: java, regex, string, performance, xml-parsing

I have following xml file:

```
<parsedResponseMap>
    <entry>
        <key>SequenceID</key>
        <value>3258</value>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <key>messageID</key>
        <value>11</value>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <key>ConnectionID</key>
        <value>1</value>
    </entry>
</parsedResponseMap>
```

In above XML i want only 11 (**value of messageID key**). I have performance issues.  If i parse xml then my performance down and i want only one value from xml. So any other way that can i get value with better performance.

Comment: Use XSLT and/or XPATH

Comment: Did you fix it? Did an answer fixed this? Please respond on the question you ask dude..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class ExtractValueFromXml {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        String lineBefore = "<key>messageID</key>";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<value>(.+?)</value>");
        String numberFound = null;

        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file.xml"))) {
            String line = null;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                if (line.matches(lineBefore)) {
                    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(br.readLine());
                    if (matcher.find()) {
                        numberFound = matcher.group(1);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            System.out.println(numberFound);

        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can always achieve this by `substring` method which I think is faster than parsing whole xml.

```
s.substring(s.indexOf("<value>", s.indexOf("<key>messageID</key>"))+7, s.indexOf("</value>", s.indexOf("<key>messageID</key>")))
```

Here is what you do. `s` is your xml string, then you substring the content

from

```
s.indexOf("<value>", s.indexOf("<key>messageID</key>"))+7
```

which stands for index of `<value>` node but this one which is assigned for key messageId

to

```
s.indexOf("</value>", s.indexOf("<key>messageID</key>"))
```

which stands for index of `</value>` node this one which is assigned for key messageId

The value `7` is there to skip the length of `<value>` element.

Comment: Why not? The length of `<value>` string will be always `7` so we can hardcode it.

Comment: I would really like to hear from people who downvote my answer what is their explanation ;)